# Fill missing dates in mysql query range

Tags: mysql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have the following query:

```
select date(updated_at) as data, COUNT(id) as numar 
from `coupons`
where `user_id` = 5 and `won_by` != 0 and `updated_at` >= '2016-04-01'
group by DAY(updated_at), month(updated_at), year(updated_at)
```

and the result is this:

```
2016-04-01-   229
2016-04-03-   30
2016-04-04-   6
2016-04-07-   1
2016-04-08-   1
2016-04-10-   1
```

What can I do to receive something like this:

```
2016-04-01-   229
2016-04-02-   0
2016-04-03-   30
2016-04-04-   6
2016-04-05-   0
2016-04-06-   0
2016-04-07-   1
2016-04-08-   1
2016-04-10-   1
```

Comment: Why don't you `GROUP BY date(updated_at)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way that I've found to do this is to simply create (and maintain) a secondary table with a single column, containing all of the dates that you care about. Something like:

CREATE TABLE date_join (
    date date not null primary key
  );

Then insert records for each date in whatever way is convenient (by hand, if it's a one-off, as part of your daily process, via stored procedure, etc).

At that point, it's simply a left join of date_join and your initial query, with a CASE statement to translate NULLs to 0s:

```
SELECT dj.date, q.numar
  FROM      date_join dj
  LEFT JOIN (select date(updated_at) as date, COUNT(id) as numar 
               from `coupons`
              where `user_id` = 5 and `won_by` != 0 and `updated_at` >= '2016-04-01'
              group by DATE(updated_at)
            ) q
         ON dj.date = q.date
   ORDER BY dj.date;
```

Comment: A table with 100K dates (200+ years) will consume about 2.5MB in MySQL. No need to ever maintain it in your life :-)